# Apollo Server - bypass the resolver when querying only the ID

Tags: performance, graphql, apollo-server

This is a question about optimising resolver behaviour by avoiding unnecessary lookups.

- I have a GraphQL schema like this:

  ```
  type User {
    id: Int!
    nationality: Country!
    # ...
  }

  type Country {
    isoCode: String!
    name: String!
  }
  ```
- In my database `user` table I have a column for `nationalityIsoCode` where I store the user's nationality such as `GB`.
- I have another `nationality` table in which I store all the country names indexed by country code.
- In my `User.nationality` resolver I use the `nationalityIsoCode` to query the `nationality` table to load the country name.

All fine.

But sometimes the client sends a query such as `query { user(id: 1) { nationality { code } } }`. In this case I don't need to query the `nationality` table because I already have the country code from the user object.

Is there an elegant way to apply this optimisation in Apollo Server?